# How do I update my inventory table based on multiple ingredient used in a recipe

Tags: sql

How do I update my inventory table based on multiple ingredient used in a recipe i.e. currentstock minus multiple quantity of ingredient used based on ingredient name e.g currentstock = currentstock - qty (for qty1, qty2, qty3 ... qty20) I tried the following queries but can only get one qty to work, it does not loop to calculate current stock based on other ingredient qty of the same recipe. This is the query I used and this is my result:

```
UPDATE TraceabilityReceiver SET TraceabilityReceiver!CurrentStock = ([CurrentStock]-Forms!FormulaWriterForm!Qty)
WHERE (((TraceabilityReceiver.ItemCode)=Forms!FormulaWriterForm!Ingredient) And ((TraceabilityReceiver.LotStatus)="Active")) OR (((TraceabilityReceiver.ItemCode)=Forms!FormulaWriterForm!Ingredient1) And ((TraceabilityReceiver.LotStatus)="Active")) OR (((TraceabilityReceiver.ItemCode)=Forms!FormulaWriterForm!Ingredient1) And ((TraceabilityReceiver.LotStatus)="Active"));
```

Comment: Is it MS Access?

Comment: Maybe you should be trying SET TraceabilityReceiver.CurrentStock.  Use a period instead of an exclamation point.  Is this SQL being run on a form or on the database table?